# MySql some columns into a single row

Tags: mysql

I have an employee table like below:

```
Emp_id Name Salary
1      Abc   10
2      Acd   90
3      Bcd   40
```

And, a degrees table like below:

```
Degree_Id Degree_name College_Id College_name Emp_Id
1            UG           1          MIT          2
2            PG           3          Harvard      2
1            UG           1          MIT          1
2            PG           3          Harvard      1
```

Above table stores various degrees acquired by the employee.

I need output like below:

```
Emp_Id  College_1  College_2
2        MIT        Harvard
1        MIT        Harvard
```

What should be my query for this? My database is MySql.

Comment: How many colleges exist? Is there a possibility that someone has been in more than two colleges? which colleges should be in `College_1` column and which in `College_2`?

Comment: @xpy..
An employee could have acquired any number of degrees from any number of colleges. All that data would be stored in the Degrees table. 
I need to find out a list which shows number of colleges attended by every employee. So, columns College_1 and College_2 can increase depending on the employee.

Comment: Then you will need to `pivot` the table, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to realize a similar effect, but not exactly the same as your expectation.

```
SELECT
Emp_id,
GROUP_CONCAT(College_name ORDER BY College_name DESC SEPARATOR '  ') Colleges
FROM degree
GROUP BY Emp_id
ORDER BY Emp_id DESC;

mysql> SELECT
    -> Emp_id,
    -> GROUP_CONCAT(College_name ORDER BY College_name DESC SEPARATOR '  ') Colleges
    -> FROM degree
    -> GROUP BY Emp_id
    -> ORDER BY Emp_id DESC;
+--------+--------------+
| Emp_id | Colleges     |
+--------+--------------+
|      2 | MIT  Harvard |
|      1 | MIT  Harvard |
+--------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is there no way to bring the colleges info in different columns?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Check if this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns